# Jquery upgrade from 1.3.1 to 1.5.1 throwing error at removeAttr on IE7

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and in IE7 alone the browser crashes , this is some legacy code. Finally i tried various debugging by making alert statements and found that problem is at line **$(this).removeAttr('myCustomattr');**

I want to know why this is started breaking after i upgrade from jquery1.3.1 to jquery1.5.1
The remove attr is working fine in all other browsers except IE7.

May i know what is real issue with this **removeAttr** with latest jquery.

If i switch to **jquery1.3.1** , it started working again.

**removeAttr** is throwing error , if i comment that it works

```
  $('#myImgagesDiv img').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('myCustomattr')) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('myCustomattr'));
        $(this).removeAttr('myCustomattr'); // code creating problem
    };
});
```

Comment: It does work for me fine in IE7 using jquery 1.6.1. Why are you not switching to the latest version?

Comment: @AR is it , then do you think my html has some problem. I already upgraded to jquery1.5.1 , then olny i got into this problem

Comment: I don't know about 1.5.1 though - I'm saying I've tested with 1.6.1 - which is the latest version.

Comment: @if you don't mind can you give a try with jquery1.5.1

Comment: @kobe, I think it's more helpful for *you* to try 1.6.1. Later versions often fix bugs in the previous ones (in this case it may have reverted a bug introduced in an earlier version). Also, it's always helpful to post the *exact error message*.

Comment: @Box9 , there is no error message for me , in ie7 the browser simply crashes , we started project 3 months ago and that time there was only jquery1.5.1 availabe, now if i upgreated the version , i have to tell the QA team to regress the whole website again,

Comment: I could not replicate your problem, it works fine for me; BTW - you shouldn't have much (if at all) problems going from 1.5.1 to 1.6.1.